# Problems with a bit array

Tags: c, arrays, sieve-of-eratosthenes, bitarray

I have macros which initialize a bit array. In typeBitVector_t name[0] I store its size, everything else I use for the actual sieve of eratosthenes. That's why I always increment index/LIMIT by 1. This is the code:

```
typedef unsigned long typeBitVector_t;
#define LIMIT (8*sizeof(unsigned long))
#define createArray(name,size) \
    typeBitVector_t name[1 + size/LIMIT + ((size%LIMIT) != 0)] = {size, 0};    
#define whatSize(name) \
    name[0]
#define setBitValue(name, index, value) \
    (name[(index/LIMIT)+1] = (value)) ? (name[(index/LIMIT)+1] |= (1<<(index%LIMIT))) : (name[(index/LIMIT)+1] &= ~(1<<(index%LIMIT)));
#define returnBitValue(name, index) \
    (name[(index/LIMIT)+1] & (1<<(index%LIMIT))) ? 1 : 0

int main(void)
{
    createArray(myArray,100);
    unsigned long bounds = (unsigned long) sqrt(100);

    for(int i = 2; i <= bounds; i++)
    {
        if((returnBitValue(myArray,i)) == 0)
        {
            for(int j = i; i * j <= bounds; j++)
            {
                setBitValue(myArray, i*j, 1);
                printf("The bit on index %d has the value %d\n", i*j, returnBitValue(myArray, i*j));
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\nTest out of the cycle\nThe bit on index %d has the value %d\n", 8, returnBitValue(myArray, 8));
}
```

I enclose the output of this program:

```
$ ./program
The bit on index 4 has the value 1
The bit on index 6 has the value 1
The bit on index 8 has the value 1
The bit on index 10 has the value 1
The bit on index 9 has the value 1

Test out of the cycle
The bit on index 8 has the value 0
```

So the sieve is working "fine" in the cycle (it now lists every non prime value between 2 and 10) but out of the cycle it's reset? Where is the problem?

Comment: As a side note, C supports *functions* so you don't really need all those macros..

Comment: Of course I don't, this is an assignment obviously. I just can't figure out this one bit (ironic huh).

Comment: Hint: The bug occurs because you use macros instead of functions. Maybe that is a more convincing argument not to use macros

Comment: Not using macros isn't an option. Could you please be more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
returnBitValue(myArray, i*j)
```

Expands to

```
(name[(i*j/LIMIT)+1] & (1<<(i*j%LIMIT))) ? 1 : 0
```

Which is different from what you probably intended:

```
(name[((i*j)/LIMIT)+1] & (1<<((i*j)%LIMIT))) ? 1 : 0
```

So at the very least you will need to add parantheses around `index` in the macro expansion. But it will still break if you try to do something like

```
returnBitValue(myArray, i++)
```

so better don't use macros at all if you can avoid it (although I understand that it seems to be a specific condition to not use functions in this case).

You also have some more problems in `setBitValue`:

```
(name[((index)/LIMIT)+1] = (value)) ? (... |= ...) : (... &= ...)
```

You probably meant

```
name[((index)/LIMIT)+1] = (value) ? (... | ...) : (... & ...)
```

You also have a potential integer overflow: `1` has type `int`, but you treat it as a `long`. Use `1L` instead.

Comment: OK thanks a lot, I added brackets around the indexes in the macros. But I still get 0 on the bit out of the cycle.. :(

Comment: @imre Have you tried any sort of debugging? Printing out the array or somesuch?

Comment: I have printed out the whole array after the cycle ended and the only value that is set to 1 is 9. Which is the last value set. So I guess anything else kind of resets? Does that help?

Comment: What do you mean? Like brackets-wrong? I've put brackets around every "index" in the macros.

Comment: With this edit made, all the bits are now 0. The 9 is also 0. Thanks so much for your input so far.

Comment: @imre: The problem with that code that it uses way too much one-line magic, macros and parentheses. I fixed it the way I described and it works. Probably you made some other mistake in the process

Comment: @imre No, but everything you need is in the answer

Answer (score 0):

indexing bit value error. Correct to (name[index / 8] & (1<<(index % 8)))

index / 8 is byte in array[0..Size], index % 8 is bit in that byte